Data serialized in Rails 6 cannot be parsed in Rails 7
This seems insane to me.  We are upgrading our app from Rails 6.1.7.7 to rails 7.1.3.4 and ruby 3.3.2 to 3.3.4.
In our items model, we have a simple serializer:
serialize :keywords, coder: JSON, type: Array
We have millions of records stored using this form our 6.1.7.7 app and can write and read from it without issue:
Loading production environment (Rails 6.1.7.7)
irb(main):001> i = Item.find(4443084)
=>
#<Item:0x00007f6b6fb909d8
...
irb(main):002> i.keywords
=> "brain,web design,mind-blowing,development,vintage"

but when we attempt to read the EXACT same data using our Rails 7 app, it crashes:
Loading production environment (Rails 7.1.3.4)
irb(main):001> i = Item.find(4443084)
An error occurred when inspecting the object: #<JSON::ParserError:"unexpected token at '--- brain,web design,mind-blowing,development,vintage\n'">
Result of Kernel#inspect: #<Item:0x00007f52b5e882d0 @new_record=false, @attributes=#<ActiveModel::LazyAttributeSet:0x00007f52b5ed0cd8 @attributes={"id"=>#<ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
...

I can't seem to find anything on this at all!  We used serialize in many places in our app and if we can't read any of them in our Rails 7 app, we're in trouble.
How do we fix this?  Why would the same coder and type not work the same between the two?

Looks like that value was serialized in YAML, not json.

@dbugger agreed but why does the coder in Rails 6.1 allow for it to still be parsed where it fails in Rails 7?

there were changes in serialization in Rails 7. Suggest you fix the inconsistency between the specified encoding (JSON) and actual encoding (YAML).

And possibly look at replacing it with native JSON/array columns or a real table. You don't need to store unqueryable junk data in 2024.

The guys from the Rails team answered this for me:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/52445#issuecomment-2258245648
In short - Rails 6.1 ignores the coder keyword in serialize, therefore the JSON was defaulting to YAML.  So in Rails 7, where the coder keyword is supported, it was trying to parse YAML as JSON.
